# how to make my windows server 2008 hosting multi websites 

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, hosting

I have vps with windows 2008 r2 standard . I have one static IP for server . I want to host multiple websites on my vps . but I am confused to use dns server or pointing domains to that IP and bind host names in iis7 only to each domain associated . and what is the best using dns server or using domain free dns server and pointing only to ip address.

Answer (score 3):

Use Host Headers to serve multiple domains from single static ip within IIS7:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(WS.10).aspx

Consider using [Zerigo](http://www.zerigo.com) for DNS, they are fantastic and its hassle free. (paid service)